# Unable to get access IMPI / BIOS / Intel Xeon Gen2 compatibility issue?

Tags: central-processing-unit, bios, bmc

I've bought new( not used )  SuperMicro MBD-X11DPI and

- x2 - Intel Xeon Silver 4210R OEM
- Micron [MTA72ASS8G72PSZ-2S6E1] 64Gb
- Samsung [M393A8G40MB2-CTD] 64Gb

When I'm booting, 10 different combinations of 2xCPU and different RAM modules give me always such picture:

```
System Initializing...
P1-DIMMA1:DIMM Mapped Out
P1-DIMMA1(runtime)Failing DIMM: DIMM location
MAP Failure
All channels are disabled due to memory test failures
```

In the right / bottom corner blinks codes: AF - BB - B7 - BB - 53

https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AMI_BIOS_POST_Codes_for_Grantley_Motherboards.pdf

- 0xAF Exit Boot Services event
- 0xB8 – 0xBF Reserved for future AMI codes - ...
- 0xB7 Configuration Reset (reset of NVRAM settings)
- 0x53 Memory initialization error. No usable memory detected

Google said, that I shall update BIOS to use gen2 Xeon on this board, seems.

Moreover, I've gained IMPI access via LAN / browser, but I can not log-in with default ADMIN/ADMIN

> Invalid Username or Password

From the manual, I have understood that IMPI shall be enabled from BIOS. So, by default it should not even answer me by http. But it answers... Strange...

Ssh - connected to 22 with ADMIN@192.168.10.12, but "ADMIN" - is incorrect password it's said. admin/admin, ADMIN/admin, admin/ADMIN, root/toor - everything is not valid...

```
# ssh ADMIN@192.168.10.12 
ADMIN@192.168.10.12's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ADMIN@192.168.10.12's password:
```

ipmitool the same:

```
# ipmitool -H 192.168.10.12 -U ADMIN  -P ADMIN
Activate Session error: Command response could not be provided
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v1.5 / RMCP session
```

USB Keyboard inserted in USB0 - does not seems to response also. So, I can not enter to BIOS. I'm only seeing this blue on black `SupermicrO` ascii label and

```
All channels are disabled due to memory test failures
System Initializing...                                     53
```

Is it right, that I can not enter to BIOS without installed proper Processor and RAM module, or BMC module shall give me VGA via controller even without CPU installed and pass me to the BIOS?

Is the buying older gen1 Intel Xeon - to boot, to update BIOS is only way to launch this setup for me, or there exist bypass?

Comment: The default password is not "admin". It is now unique for every server, and included with the system paperwork.

Comment: Many many many thanx Michael, I'm in. But there is no paperwork, it is situated on sticker, right on board and second one on CPU1’s plastic protective cover, see https://www.supermicro.com/support/BMC_Unique_Password_Guide.pdf

Comment: Close enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I've used this perl script: https://github.com/bwachter/supermicro-ipmi-key

Thereafter, updated BIOS to 3.3 and it started working... Motherboard still can not recognize two CPU, but I'm able to launch 1 CPU and 196GB of RAM.

Thanks to Michael Hampton.